# Upload attachment to Google Sites using Powershell (Invoke-RestMethod)

Tags: powershell, google-api, powershell-3.0, google-sites

I need to upload files to my Google Sites website from Powershell.

I've got the OAuth part working fine, as well as several other API functions, but I can't work out how to upload binary data this way.

Based on [this page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#UploadingFiles), here's the function I've written:

```
Function UploadFileToGoogleSites {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $OAuth2ServiceAccountToken,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $Domain,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $SiteName,
        $ParentEntryID = '',
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $FilePath,
        $FileName = '',
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $FileType
    )

    if ( $FileName -eq '' ) {
        $FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($FilePath)
    }

    $requestUri = "https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/$($Domain)/$($SiteName)"

    $requestHeaders = @{ Authorization = $OAuth2ServiceAccountToken; 'GData-Version' = 1.4 }

    $requestContentType = 'multipart/related; boundary=_BOUNDARY_'

    $requestBody = @"
    --_BOUNDARY_
    Content-Type: application/atom+xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#attachment" label="attachment" />
        <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008#parent" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/$($Domain)/$($SiteName)/$($ParentEntryID)" />
        <atom:title>$($FileName)</atom:title>
    </atom:entry>

    --_BOUNDARY_
    Content-Type: $($FileType)
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

    $([System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)))

    --_BOUNDARY_--
    "@

    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $requestUri -Headers $requestHeaders -ContentType $requestContentType -Body $requestBody
}
```

This is then called like this:

```
UploadFileToGoogleSites -OAuth2ServiceAccountToken $oAuth2ServiceAccountToken -Domain $domain -SiteName $siteName -FilePath 'C:\temp\image.png -FileType 'image/png'
```

It seems that Google Sites is not recognising the Base64 encoding of the binary data - uploading a simple text file results in a text file being successfully created in the Google Site but the contents are the Base64 data, not the original text.

The same occurs for binary types, for example uploading a PNG image file (with `-FileType 'image/png'`) results in a PNG file being created which is really just a text file, with the base64 data as the contents, but with the PNG extension.

Obviously removing the Base64 encoding step (i.e. replacing `$([System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)))` with something like `$(Get-Content $FilePath)`) would work for text files, the file is created correctly, however not only does this cause issues with incompatible characters, it doesn't work for binary files (which is what is really needed in this case).

Has anyone got any suggestions on how to upload attachments to Google Sites using Powershell?

Comment: Maybe try with `application/octet-stream` as content type?

Comment: @Vesper: Unfortunately no deal, that produces the same result. It seems the 'Content-Type:' header isn't being used at all.